# Using for loop to add nested key value pairs in a Map

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a **Map<String, dynamic>** of the structure **{'a': data, 'b': {'c': {'key':data}}}**.

I want to use a for loop to add additional key value pairs to *'b'* but can't find a way to do so. **addAll** overwrites **'b'** during every iteration which is the behavior of **addAll** provided there is an existing key...anyone have ideas on how this can be accomplished?

My other thought on how to do this is to create a new map **secondMap**. This is able to create a map without key value pairs being overwritten...but then I am stuck on how I can combine the **secondMap** to the **myMap** under **'b'**

```
  for (var i = 0; i <= info.length - 1; i++) {
          myMap.addAll({'b': {info[i].name: {'key': data}
                      }});
//method 2
  for (var i = 0; i <= info.length - 1; i++) {
          secondMap.addAll({info[i].name: {'key': data}}
                      );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this sample code helps you.

```
void main() {
  
 final Map<String, dynamic> map = {'a': "data", 'b': {}};
  
  for (int i = 0; i < 10 ; i++) {
    map['b'][i.toString()] = {"key": i};
  }
  
  print(map);
}
```